# Extract value from scala TimeStampType

Tags: scala, hive, hiveql

I have a schemaRDD created from a hive query

```
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
    val rdd = sqlContext.sql("Select * from mytime")
```

My RDD contains the following schema

```
    StructField(id,StringType,true)
    StructField(t,TimestampType,true)
```

We have our own custom database and want to same the TimestampType to a string. But I could not find a way to extract the value and save it as a string.

Can you help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change your query to:

```
SELECT id, cast(t as STRING) from mytime
```